# Signed cookies using lambda@edge

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I'm using a lambda@edge, viewer request to include signed cookies in my application, but for some reason the cookies are not set in the headers, I followed the example of this documentation (https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/signed-cookie-based-authentication-with-amazon-cloudfront-and-aws-lambdaedge-part-2-authorization)I did a test and proved that the application actually finds the lambda@edge, but cookies are not set at all